# Python Selenium can't get name of product if that name is too long

Tags: python, html, string, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape all products (name, image, price and link) from https://www.nguyenkim.com/tim-kiem.html?tu-khoa=may+tinh but if the product's name is too long like "Máy tính để bàn HP 205 Pro G4 AIO R5-4500U/8GB/256GB/Win10 31Y21PA" - the product card can't display its all, lead to the name and price become empty string but image, link return correct value.

Value return if everything is normal:

```
Item(
    link = 'https://www.nguyenkim.com/chuot-logitech-m100r.html',
    name = 'Chuột máy tính Logitech M100R Đen',
    current_price = '109.000đ',
    place = 'Nguyen Kim',
    img = 'https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/210/210/detailed/177/10026584-chuot-logitech-m100r-den-1.jpg'
)
```

Value return if name too long:

```
Item(
    link = 'https://www.nguyenkim.com/may-tinh-bang-xiaomi-redmi-pad-64gb-xam.html',
    name = '',
    current_price = '',
    place = 'Nguyen Kim',
    img = 'https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/210/210/detailed/847/10053972-may-tinh-bang-xiaomi-redmi-pad-64gb-xam.jpg'
)
```

What I have tried:

```
    content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'result-wrapper')
    items = content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product')
    for _ in items:
        item = Item(
          link = _.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='product-header']").get_attribute('href'),
          name = _.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-title a").text,
          current_price = _.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p[class*='final-price']").text,
          place = "Nguyen Kim",
          img = _.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img").get_attribute('src')
        )
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can find a straightforward way to get those full items names. You do not need the overheads of Selenium for this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import json

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_list = []
for i in range(1,3):
    r = s.get(f'https://www.nguyenkim.com/tim-kiem.html?tu-khoa=may+tinh&trang={i}')
    soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
    all_prods = soup.select('script[class="script-render"]')
    for prod in all_prods:
        prod_data = json.loads(prod.string.split('dataRenderProduct.push(')[1].split(');')[0])
        big_list.append(prod_data)
df = pd.json_normalize(big_list)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    id  product_code    has_shock_price     has_flash_sale  image_url   big_image_url   link    origin_price    final_price     origin_price_int    list_price  final_price_int     price   product     display_name    name    nk_shortname    discount_percent    discount_percent_num    saved   is_installment  installment_bank    is_bestseller   short_desc  hidden_option   tags    tag_image_special   tag_overlay_special     tag_start_time_special  tag_end_time_special    tag_position_special    promotion_text  product_id  category_ids    percent_discount    coupon_text     cf_is_tra_gop   thumb
0   124425  000000000010053665-CAI      False   https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/210/210/detailed/836/10053665-may-tinh-de-ban-hp-205-pro-g4-aio-r5-4500u-31y21pa-1.jpg  https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/500/500/detailed/836/10053665-may-tinh-de-ban-hp-205-pro-g4-aio-r5-4500u-31y21pa-1.jpg  https://www.nguyenkim.com/may-tinh-de-ban-hp-205-pro-g4-aio-31y21pa.html    16.590.000đ     11.990.000đ     16590000    16590000    11990000    11990000    Máy tính để bàn HP 205 Pro G4 AIO R5-4500U/8GB/256GB/Win10 31Y21PA  Máy tính để bàn HP 205 Pro G4 AIO R5-4500U/8GB/256GB/Win10 31Y21PA  Máy tính để bàn HP 205 Pro G4 AIO R5-4500U/8GB/256GB/Win10 31Y21PA      -28%    -28%    4.600.000đ  True    None    False   <p>Thiết kế tinh tế, kiểu dáng hiện đại với chân đế chữ X chắc chắn</p>\r\n<p>Tích hợp đủ hệ thống phần mềm, camera,... mà không cần CPU</p>\r\n<p>Bộ vi xử lý R5-4500U cho hiệu năng mạnh mẽ, xử lý tốt mọi tác vụ</p>\r\n<p>RAM 8GB đa nhiệm có thể mở 4-5 ứng dụng mà không bị giật, lag</p>\r\n<p>Ổ cứng 256GB mang đến không gian lưu trữ vừa đủ, mở máy nhanh</p>\r\n<p>Màn hình Full HD có kích thước 23.8inch hiển thị hình ảnh sắc nét</p>\r\n<p>Máy được trang bị Webcam 5MP nâng cao chất lượng cuộc đàm thoại</p>   N   None        None    1666803600  1666889999  None        124425  [341, 529, 554]     28      False   []
1   105706  000000000010049553-BO       False   https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/210/210/detailed/734/may-tinh-bang-samsung-galaxy-tab-a7-lite-32gb-bac.jpg  https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/500/500/detailed/734/may-tinh-bang-samsung-galaxy-tab-a7-lite-32gb-bac.jpg  https://www.nguyenkim.com/may-tinh-bang-samsung-galaxy-tab-a7-lite-32gb-bac.html    4.490.000đ  3.290.000đ  4490000     4490000     3290000     3290000     Máy tính bảng Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 Lite 32GB Bạc   Máy tính bảng Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 Lite 32GB Bạc   Máy tính bảng Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 Lite 32GB Bạc       -27%    -27%    1.200.000đ  True    None    False   <p>Màn hình 8.7 inch WXGA+ (1340x800) hiển thị hình ảnh rõ nét, chân thực</p>\r\n<p>CPU Mediatek MT8768T cho hiệu năng ổn định, xử lý tác vụ nhanh chóng</p>\r\n<p>Dung lượng pin 5100 mAh, sạc nhanh 15W, thoải mái trải nghiệm cả ngày</p>\r\n<p>Trải nghiệm âm thanh sống động với Hệ thống loa kép và Dolby Atmos </p>  N   None        None    1622048400  1622134799  None        105706  [340, 528, 549]     27      False   []
2   90168   000000000010042749-CHI      False   https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/210/210/detailed/618/10042749_MHMT_ACER_R241Y-23-8INCH_UM-QR1SS-B01_01.jpg  https://cdn.nguyenkimmall.com/images/thumbnails/500/500/detailed/618/10042749_MHMT_ACER_R241Y-23-8INCH_UM-QR1SS-B01_01.jpg  https://www.nguyenkim.com/man-hinh-may-tinh-acer-r241y.html     4.090.000đ  4.090.000đ  4090000     4090000     4090000     4090000     Màn hình máy tính Acer R241Y    MÀN HÌNH MÁY TÍNH ACER R241Y 23.8"  MÀN HÌNH MÁY TÍNH ACER R241Y 23.8"      None        None    True    None    False   <p>Màn hình LED 23.8 inch, hiển thị rõ nét</p>\r\n<p>Thời gian phản hồi màn hình cực nhạy 1 ms</p>\r\n<p>Độ phân giải Full HD, mang đến hình ảnh sống động</p>\r\n<p>Thiết kế viền siêu mỏng cho trải nghiệm hình ảnh độc đáo</p>\r\n<p>Khả năng tái chế, giảm chất thải, tiết kiệm năng lượng</p>\r\n<p>Có thể điều chỉnh độ nghiêng của màn hình dễ dàng </p>    N   None        None    1572454800  1572541199  None        90168   [341, 530, 559]     0       False   []
[...]
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and Requests docs [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
EDIT: Improved the code, to bring in full product details.

Comment: wow. thanks you so much. beautifulsoup4 solution is much simpler than selenium one. But i still don't know where to find script[class="script-render"] after read the documentation. Can you help me with that.

Comment: That's in page HTML. Just inspect page, and you will see the elements.

Comment: sorry for keep asking but i can only find the script in the network tab but can't find its class anywhere. Is there a trick/tip to find it

Comment: Right click on page, select `View page source`. Once that loads, write Ctrl+F and search for `class="script-render"`.